# {php} {/php} What is the syntax for php tags in curly braces

Tags: php, smarty

I am working with some class file that call an html template file. Below is a fragment of the code.

Sample Code:

```
  <table>
<tr>
    <td align="left">{php} xl('Subjective','e'); {/php}</td>
    <td width="90%">
        <textarea name="subjective" cols="60" rows="6">{$data->get_subjective()}      </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">{php} xl('Objective','e'); {/php}</td>
    <td width="90%">
        <textarea name="objective" cols="60" rows="6">{$data->get_objective()}         </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">{php} xl('Assessment','e'); {/php}</td>
    <td width="90%">
        <textarea name="assessment" cols="60" rows="6">{$data->get_assessment()}     </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">{php} xl('Plan','e'); {/php}</td>
    <td width="90%">
        <textarea name="plan" cols="60" rows="6">{$data->get_plan()}</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
            <tr>
    <td align="left">{php} xl('Signature','e'); {/php}</td>
    <td width="90%" height='50'>
                 Signed by: {php} if($s == 1){ echo "Dr. Hagg";} {/php}
    </td>
</tr>
```

where I am having the problem is I am trying to do this:

```
{php}

 $s = $data->get_sig();

{/php}
```

The  $data->get_sig() returns a value of 1.

When I do enter the code above, the program errors. I don't have errors turned on so I don't see the error but I am willing to bet it is a syntax error. Because if I just put $s = 1; in there. The code runs.

I have searched google and have not found anything.

I have tried:

```
  {php}

  $s = "'.$data->get_sig().'";

  {/php}
```

Can you help me with what syntax I should be using?
Thank you.

Comment: this is [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) right?

Comment: You'll have to tell us what templating system you're using, such as Smarty. I presume you've already tried `<?php` and `?>`?

Comment: What is `{php}`?  What framework/library/templating engine are you using?  "I don't have errors turned on".  Why not?  You're developing, they should be turned on.  Turn them on.

Comment: Do you have access to your server's error log? The errors might be in there even if they don't display.

Comment: Yes, I can check the server logs

Comment: I don't have a pure development environment. I have to share the server with production. So, I can't turn them on at the server level but I will turn them on at the file level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is the right way to access smarty objects

Try this:

```
{assign var="s" value=$data->get_sig()}
```

Note: Do not surround this with {php}...{/php}

You can check the documentation for objects [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.objects.tpl).

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried this seven ways from sunday and still could not get this to work.

Comment: I reviewed the link and tried to figure out how to register the obj to a variable.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I had to take out the double quotes and use single quotes. That let me assign the s variable to object.

Comment: Sounds strange. I'm not sure why double quotes don't work. Anyways it's good to know that your problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score -1):

PHP usually opens and closes as `<?php ... ?>`

And make sure that your function `echo` some stuff. If it returns then make

```
<?php echo xl(...); ?>
```

Comment: tried this and it returned the code in the php tags.

Comment: what is the file extension?

Comment: It sounds like it must not be .php. Probably .html if he's using a templating system.

Comment: Probably a .tpl file, that's what smarty uses